# Using arrays to group properties together in a Javascript class rather than listing each one as it's own property

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, properties

I'm brand new to javascript (2nd week of learning) so I'm sorry if this is a stupid question! I've found 2 ways to do the thing I'm trying to do and need some advice on whether the second way is acceptable.

I know a class can have properties that take arrays where the array lists multiple values of that one property. However, if I have a class with properties that are group-able (relate to the same aspect of the object) can I make them into one property that takes an array rather than listing each as a property?

So, if I have a `Tent` class with a `mainUses` property, I know I can pass a new instance an array for a tent that has multiple main uses.

```
class Tent {
constructor(mainUses){
this.mainUses = mainUses;}}; 

const myTent = new Tent (["Backpacking","Mountaineering","Bikepacking"]);
```

And if I also have a minimum pack weight, standard weight and maximum weight for the tent I can do:

```
class Tent {
constructor(mainUses,minWeight,standardWeight,maxWeight){
this.mainUses = mainUses;
this.minWeight = minWeight;
this.standardWeight = standardWeight;
this.maxWeight = maxWeight;}};

const myTent = new Tent (["Backpacking","Mountaineering","Bikepacking"], "2kg","2.2kg","2.4kg");
```

But what about if I group the 3 weights into one 'super-property' (for want of a better description) like this:

```
class Tent {
constructor(mainUses,weight){
this.mainUses = mainUses;
this.weight = weight;}};
```

And then pass the 'super-property' an array listing the 3 weights:

```
const myTent = new Tent (["Backpacking","Mountaineering","Bikepacking"],["2kg","2.2kg","2.4kg"]);
```

And then, so that they can still easily be accessed, add a comment to the class listing the indices to use when I make a new instance or want to access something.

```
/*minWeight [0], standardWeight [1], maxWeight[2]*/
```

So that `myTent.minWeight` would become `myTent.weight[0]`.

Is there any reason I shouldn't do it this way? It appears to *work* for what I'm trying to do but I'm worried that it's bad form/hacky/wrong-for-some-other-reason to use it like this?

I've tried to search for an example of it being used this way but I don't really know how to describe it succinctly enough to search effectively. The example I've used doesn't show it well but where I have lots of properties that I could group into a single array, it ends up being much simpler. I feel like it's semantically...off somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this, but if you have different properties in the same array it would maybe be better to use an associative array. In my opinion, it would be better organized. It would also be more object oriented and it would still be ok if you add more properties.

```
  const myTent = [
     { item: 'Backpacking',
       weight: '2kg',
     },
     { item: 'Mountaineering',
       weight: '2.2kg',
     },
     { item: 'Bikepacking',
       weight: '2.4kg',
     },
     ];
```

Comment: I think either I explained it badly or I'm misunderstanding. 
This seems to join together the items at the first, second and third index of the 2 arrays but I'm not looking to associate the 2 arrays at all - they're entirely different lists.

Comment: In that case, this approach is ok. And it is not hacky, in my opinion, it is better to have fewer arguments as you did in the second example. Using an array makes your code able to easily handle more than just 3 parameters.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I need a lot of parameters which is why I was looking for a different way of doing it that would make it neater.

Answer (score 0):

Objects are generally used instead of arrays for this purpose because it is much easier to not get confused about which element means which thing when they are named.

```
// Weight property

{
  min: 2,
  standard: 2.2,
  max: 2.4,
  unit: 'kg',
}
```

Comment: I did think about nesting objects instead but I got a bit confused. I would need to have a Weight class within the Tent class but the Weight isn't a subclass of the Tent. I can't make a weight instance and then pass it so can I pass a class to the constructor of another class?